# Why is this C Array algorithm failing on the second iteration?

Tags: c, arrays, iteration

I'm having trouble at the `checkTotal()` function.
In the first iteration, it can sum everything with it's value correctly.

However during my second iteration, the values added up are not accurate and I'm not really sure where the numbers are coming from.

```
 int checkTotal(int numSchemes, int numComponents, int weight[numComponents][numSchemes], char **list){
     int cCounter = 0;
     int total = 0;
     while (cCounter < numComponents){
        total = total + weight[numSchemes][cCounter];
        printf("%d\n", total);
        cCounter++;
     }

     return total;
}
```

And this is the function that calls checkTotal

```
void weightInput(int numSchemes, int numComponents, int weight[numComponents][numSchemes], char **list){
    int sCounter = 0;
    int cCounter = 0;

            // iterating through the number of schemes
    while (sCounter < numSchemes){
        printf("\nMarking scheme #%d: \n", (sCounter+1));
        while (cCounter < numComponents){
            printf("\tenter %s's weight:  ", list[cCounter]);
            int theWeight;
            scanf("%d", &theWeight);
            weight[sCounter][cCounter] = theWeight;
            cCounter++; 
        }   
        //printf("%d\n", weight[sCounter][cCounter]);
        printf("THE TOTAL IS %d\n", checkTotal(sCounter, numComponents, weight, list));
        sCounter++;
        cCounter = 0;
    }
 }
```

The function takes a 2d array, iterates through the second dimension, and then adds up all int's to receive a total.

It successsfully sums up and returns the sum in the first iteration, but for my second iteration, it does now.

If I input 33, 22, 5, 5 for the first iteration, it will return 65.

For my second iteration, I would have (10, 5, 10, 25) but it would return 47 when it should be 50.

If anyone can help out, it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance,

Comment: It seems the problem is out of your function. Please produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that motivates people to help you. Consider using [Ideone](http://ideone.com).

Comment: After your edit, the possibility remains that the problem lies out of the code you have posted so far.

Comment: Using `for()` loops in `weightInput()` would make your code more legible.

Comment: this line: total = total + weight[numSchemes][cCounter]; should be: total = total + weight[numComponents][cCounter];

Comment: this line: while (cCounter < numComponents){ should be: while (cCounter < numSchemes){

Comment: this line: weight[sCounter][cCounter] = theWeight; should be: weight[cCounter][sCounter] = theWeight;

Comment: this line: int theWeight; should be moved to before the first while() statement in main()

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the logic could be potentially be back to front? You have

```
int weight[numComponents][numSchemes]
```

in the signature line, but then access it with.

```
weight[numSchemes][cCounter]
```

Should cCounter and numSchemes be the other way around?

Comment: Please mark this as your answer; this is part of your role and it contributes greatly to the quality of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

`total = total + weight[numSchemes][cCounter];`

should be:

```
total = total + weight[numComponents][cCounter];
```

Thanks @user3629249